# Field Not showing but showing on Details section for the record

Tags: configuration

I have created one field on an object but when tried to create a new record for that particular object it is not showing the newly created field(Date).

I have checked the field level security it is fine and in the Layout assignment also it is assigned but I'm not able to understand how could this be even possible

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Did you create this as a Formula field?

Comment: Have you checked if the `new` button is being [overridden](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_customize_override.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Personally sometimes when i change the Page Layouts, i need to logout-login in order to get the changes. Sometimes even hard refresh of the page doesn't work for me. Although it may sound common, if you relogin and try again, you have the same results?

Comment: There is a session cache for pages which may be causing this. You will find an org-wide setting to control this cache in Setup, under Session Management (IIRC). This is what causes what Giorgos mentioned.

Comment: Hello, Currently Lightning record page also used to show the record details.  So Please make sure, you don't assign any lightning record page for your profile (and application also) for "Expense" object. If it's assigned, You need to add the new field "Requested Delivery date" into that Lightning record page also. Then only that field can be visible to you during creation.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: This is resolved now I don't know why Salesforce is taking too much of time to reflect the changes especially on the layouta